# How to use UISwitch

Tags: ios, toggle, segue, uiswitch

I am new in Xcode, trying to build an app, and I am studying a lot; it seems not enough. Anyway, I need a step by step of 2 things:

1. my 1st Vc has 10 switch buttons and I need to limit to only 4 can be "On";
2. when my switch button is on, it changes a label in the 2nd Vc.

I am really struggling with the segues codes. Any light will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I’d suggest asking one question at a time and these two are completely different issues. I’d suggest you edit this to be one or the other, but not both. Also, show us what you’ve tried. Or if you don’t know where to start, show us what research you’ve done and what you have a question about.

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1

i. You need to have a data model of an array of Bool to store the state of the UISwitch

ii. When the value of the UISwitch changes, you have to update the value of the corresponding index of the Bool array

iii. To limit the number of `On`, you may disable all `Off` switch if the limit exceeds so that the user can only switch `On` to `Off` but not adding another `On` switch. Or you may listen to the `valueChanged` event, if the 5th switch is `On`, immediately set it back to `Off`

### Step 2

You need to learn how to pass data/objects between ViewControllers.

i. the most simple one would be having a Singleton object that can be accessed anywhere.

ii. but it may be better to have a property in the 2nd VC, just pass the data model before 2nd VC is pushed

Comment: Singleton’s for sharing model data is an anti-pattern, at best, and doesn’t belong in the list of suggestions for new developers.

Comment: Thanks all. I kind figure by myself. I am not sure the best solution, but it's working. I could make a pass when the swicth is On to another vc; it changes a label. So, I made only 4 labels and a bunch of IFs, this way, even if the user switch more than 4, only the first 4 will be taken in account...